# Link to controller action that has no model not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am following one book agile web development with rails 4th edition and I have completed most of the part through it, now I want to change something. Let me first show you what I have so far

```
Products ( controller, model, view )
Store ( controller & view )
Cart ( controller , model , view)
Line items ( controller , model view )
```

Now as you can see product can have index, show , create etc and I can access products like `: {http://localhost:3000/products/2}`

in my route file I have set my root to `store#index`

```
root :to => 'store#index', :as=>'store'
```

and on store I have following

```
class StoreController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @products=Product.all
  end
end
```

I just want to access products and show one individual product from this controller. I tried

```
<%= link_to "Show", store %>
```

but it is not working. Please remember that I do not have any Model for Store.

Comment: "I just want to access products and show one individual product from this controller" <- Which _individual_ product do you want to show? That last `erb` code is completely wrong.

Comment: Define “not working”. What is actually happening vs. what you expect to happen. Post an error messages you get.

Answer (score 1):

You should specify your controller and method:

```
link_to "Show", :controller => "store", :action => "index"
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use:

```
<%= link_to "Show", root_path %>
```

Since you used as: in your routes, you may also use:

```
<%= link_to "Show", store_path %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wan to display the store index you should create a route for it:

```
get '/store', :to => "store#index", :as => "store"
```

And then you can create the link:

```
<%= link_to "Show", store_path %>
```

You don't need a model to create routes, routes will redirect to the assigned action